# MBP 2019 13" 4x Thunderbolt 3 ports (electric ESC button)

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, hardware, thunderbolt

A novice here. I got a PC repair kit to open my titular MBP machine to clean under the trackpad. After success, I closed it and everything working normal.

Found a missing washer, opened it again to put it back, and in the reconnection of the power cable the tiny black plastic bit to lock it down snapped out, still got the cable all the way in. Otherwise, everything is fine.

But MBP won't work without a recharge cord plugged in and the battery doesn't register. Is that little black lockdown piece on the power cable logic board receiver really the issue?

MBP now overclocks the fans and nothing takes less than a minutes to proceed or decide a function. The battery doesn't register and cannot be located through the system.

Can this be fixed or am I looking at a new device??

Comment: can we see (pic) the broken plug

Comment: did you reset the SMC ?

Comment: @ruskes I thought I could upload a photo I took of said broken part here, but the site is too techy for me to figure out (I have a little dyscalculia to contend with- great with reason bad with code/numers) how to code my photo in.

I did look up SMC and perform it for my 2019 machine, battery still MIA/non-operational.

Comment: @ruskes timestamp 6:12 - the tiny black flip up lacth locking the power cable down, that broke off of mine, and the side wall of the box it and the cable plug into, broke away. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9AtOwNf3VI

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description and the video, you might have damaged the Battery board Data cable. That is data cable, not the power cable.

Without it the MBP does not knows if battery exists.

Possible problem was: **Slide parallel to the logic board. Don't pull up.**

You might be able to find replacement cable and hope it will work.

Source: Ifixit
[image: cable]